do you have any customization way of flutter tradingview chart for Coins Exchange app?
do you have any customization of flutter tradingview chart for Coins Exchange app?
i'm trying to customize tradingview plugin but there is no flutter widget i have to show via flutter webview which is not fully customize that's why i need flutter widget to full customization

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

thank you so much all, this problem solved Alhamdulillah, and i'll share code if anyone needed but the code not centralized that's why not share
